# Samsung 3D Explorer app

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, samsung-smart-tv

I just bought a Samsung 3D TV and would like to develop my own app that displays 3D content on it. Is this possible?

I looked at the SDK provided by samsung, but could not find anything related to this (saw something about playing 3D content .. but nothing like a 3D API or develop your own 3D game using something like UNITY and it will display in a 3D manner on the screen).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 3D in TV Context ([Stereoscopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy)) is different with 3D Game Programming ([3 Axes Positioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_computer_graphics)).

To develop game or application that using 3D Computer Graphics you can do it by WebGL or OpenGL using PNaCl interface. And for displaying 3D Content you just put your 3D Media (usually side-by-side type) to the Media Player and press the 3D button in the remote.